# How to access rails session variable from a module inside a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm creating a gem for rails that abstracts away  bizarre third party API and having trouble with one item.
Inside my gem I have a module with a class inside that needs to access rails' session variable. Is there any way I can do this easily or do I have to do it in the ApplicationController?

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing inspiration from how the [rails-footnotes](https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes/) gem sets itself up, I would suggest adding a mixin to `ApplicationController::Base` that adds a before_filter that grabs the session and stores it where your library can easily access it (like in the same class that will invoke whatever logic needs access to it).

Comment: I realize you asked if you could do it outside of _the_ application controller, but to be far, this does it inside _all the_ application controllers :)